# How to prove $Z_{n}$ converges to $p^{2}$ in probability?

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, probability-limit-theorems

I'm solving this exercise

> [image]

and get stuck at Question 3b, i.e, *Show that $Z_{n}$ converges to $p^{2}$ in probability*.

Could you please shed me some light on 3b?

**My attempt:**

b. For $\varepsilon > 0$, we have $\mathbb P(|Z_n -p^2| > \varepsilon) = \mathbb P (Z_n \in (p^2 - \varepsilon, p^2 + \varepsilon))$.

c. We have $\mathbb E(Y_1) = \mathbb E(X_1 X_2) = \mathbb E(X_1) \mathbb E(X_2) = p^2$. Thus $$\begin{aligned}
 \mathbb E(Z_n - p^2)^2 &= {(\mathbb E(Z_n)-p^2 )}^2 +\operatorname{Var}(Z_n) \\
 &= {(\mathbb E(Y_1)-p^2 )}^2 + \operatorname{Var}(Z_n)\\
&= {(p^2-p^2 )}^2 + \frac{p^{2}\left(1-p^{2}\right)}{n}+\frac{2(n-1)\left(p^{3}-p^{4}\right)}{n^{2}} \\
&=\frac{p^{2}\left(1-p^{2}\right)}{n}+\frac{2(n-1)\left(p^{3}-p^{4}\right)}{n^{2}} \end{aligned}$$

Hence $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \mathbb E(Z_n - p^2)^2 = 0$$

Comment: Use part a which shows that the variance tends to 0. Hence Z_n cannot vary too far from its mean, E.g. Chebyshev.

Comment: Thank you so much @CalvinLin! I got it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From @Calvin Lin's comment

> Use part a which shows that the variance tends to $0$. Hence $Z_n$ cannot vary too far from its mean, E.g. Chebyshev.

I post it as an answer to peacefully close this question.